# Wrong result after compare select.val() and span.text()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a folowing problem.
On click button `Filter` I want get entries with selected city.
SO forbid me write big code, so I show only div with data. I think you can add select with options, if you want.
`(Select id = "cityFilter" , options: Dnepr, Kharkiv, Lviv)`

**HTML**:

```
<div id="data">
    <div>
        <a class="userEmail" href="#">user1@domain.ua </a>
        <span> user1 </span>
        <span> Dnepr </span>
        <span><input type = "button" value = "x" /></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a class="userEmail" href="#">user2@domain.ua </a>
        <span> user2 </span>
        <span> Kharkiv </span>
        <span><input type = "button" value = "x" /></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a class="userEmail" href="#"> user3@domain.ua </a>
        <span> user3 </span>
        <span> Lviv </span>
        <span><input type = "button" value = "x" /></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a class="userEmail" href="#"> user4@domain.ua </a>
        <span> user4 </span>
        <span> Dnepr </span>
        <span><input type = "button" value = "x" /></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a class="userEmail" href="#"> user5@domain.ua </a>
        <span> user5 </span>
        <span> Lviv </span>
        <span><input type = "button" value = "x" /></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**cityFilter.js** (The description of the code in comments):

```
$(function() {
  //click on button
  $('body > input').on('click', function() {
    //get selected value
    var cityFilter = $('#cityFilter').val();
    //sort out spans which contains city names
    $('#data > div > a + span + span').each(function() {
      //for check the received value
      console.log($(this).text());
      //compare selected value and span text
      if ($(this).text() != cityFilter) {
        console.log('true');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

I got all `true`. Where is the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your spans have leading and trailing spaces

i.e. `" abc " != "abc"`

try the following instead:

```
 if ($(this).text().trim() != cityFilter) {
    console.log('true');
  }
```

Comment: Make it an explicit compare using `!==` :)

Comment: @Arkantos that is totally irrelevant and unnecessary

Comment: exactly. Big thank you =) I forgot about this spaces.